# Installing ggplot on OSX

Tags: python, macos, pip, anaconda, python-ggplot

I installed ggplot flawlessly on anaconda using

```
pip install ggplot
```

However, if I try to install it with my non-anaconda pip I get:

```
ImportError: statsmodels requires patsy. http://patsy.readthedocs.org

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/n4/l3cggyqs1jj1_ltxl8v3dljh0000gn/T/pip_build_Leo/statsmodels
Storing debug log for failure in /var/folders/n4/l3cggyqs1jj1_ltxl8v3dljh0000gn/T/tmpfwsnyy
```

Comment: You can install patsy with conda `conda install patsy`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try installing patsy on it's own.

```
$ pip install patsy
$ pip install ggplot
$ python -c "from ggplot import *"
```